# authenticate always returns None,Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to add the authentication functionality in my application.
I have below code snippet:

```
user = User.objects.create_user('jkd')
user.set_password('space')
user.save
user = authenticate(username='jkd', password='space')
print "User:",user
```

It always prints the "User:None".
I have also added below in my settings.py file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # default
     # any other authentication backends
)
```

I have gone through answers of same question in different thread but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Are you sure your user is actually getting created successfully? Also when saving the user don't you have to call user.save() instead of user.save?

Comment: Yes.After user.save I have put the print like: print user.It displays the user name that is added.

Comment: Thanks Georgina S.It helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is typo in your code, thus the record has not been saved yet

Change from

```
user.save
```

to

```
user.save()
```

Comment: Georgina S should have the credit as well, cos he gave you the hint first (I just realized about that). I didn't look at the comments when posting this answer though

Comment: Yes I have up voted her comment.Is there any other way by which i can give credit to her?